# $scope.$watch inside directive not being called when it supposed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I really dont know what is going wrong with this code, I created a directive that watch the MapController's model "List" change and that should trigger some code inside the directive but unfortunally the $watch is not triggered.

=> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriobarreto/5kvhkw5j/) <=

Code:

```
 var APP = angular.module('appSite',[])
.controller('MapController', function($scope) {
$scope.List = [];


$scope.Stuff = function(){
    var oTarget = { Pos: { Lat: 10, Lng: 10 }, Des: 'Imovel 1', Id: 1 }
    $scope.List.push(oTarget);
}
})
.service('LoadGMapAPI',function($q, $window){

    this.loadScript = function() {
        var s = document.createElement('script')
        s.src = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en&callback=initMap'
        document.body.appendChild(s)
    }

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $window.initMap = function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    }

    this.loadAPI = deferred.promise;
}).directive('hitmap', ['LoadGMapAPI', function(LoadGMapAPI) {  

var link = function( $scope, elem, attrs ) 
{
    //----  HERE IS THE PROBLEM ----
    $scope.$watch('List', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if ($scope.List != undefined) { alert('Yeah !') } 
    },true);

    if ( angular.isDefined($scope.lat) && angular.isDefined($scope.lng) ) 
    {

        $scope.initialize = function() 
        {                                        
            $scope.location = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.lat, $scope.lng);

            $scope.mapOptions = {
                zoom: 3,
                center: $scope.location
            };

            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById($scope.MapID), $scope.mapOptions);

        }

          LoadGMapAPI.loadAPI.then(function () {
            $scope.initialize();
          });

          LoadGMapAPI.loadScript();
        }
    }

    return { 
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            lat: '@',
            lng: '@',
            MapID: '@id'
        }
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
 <body ng-app="appSite">
      <div ng-controller="MapController">
          <input type="button" value="Click me  to say Yeah " ng-click="Stuff()" />
          <hitmap id="mapSearch" lat="25" lng="-80.4"  />
      </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Move `$scope.$watch` to your controller instead of your directive.

Comment: Since my directive is isolated, I dont want to share specific directive business logic with the controller...

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to watch a property on your directive scope, but you've specified that your directive scope should be an [isolate scope](http://codetunnel.io/isolate-scopes-explained/).

Try this:

```
return { 
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        lat: '@',
        lng: '@',
        MapID: '@id',
        List: '=@list'
    }
}
```

---

```
<hitmap id="mapSearch" lat="25" lng="-80.4" list="List"  />
```

---

These changes configure a new two-way bound variable on your directive's isolate scope. Then you pass in the list from the parent controller to the attribute on the directive, angular sets up the two-way binding between the controller variable and the directive variable. Now you can successfully `$watch` the `'List'` inside your link function for your directive.

http://codetunnel.io/isolate-scopes-explained/

Comment: Very good link u posted there, I had problems using the `List: '=@list'`, solved using the `'='` alone. Thx for help !

Comment: No problem. Be sure to accept the answer if it got you on track :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Yeah, I was surprised and my whole problem with the Angular was mostly a "AngularJS Expression Case Sensitive Compiling Problem".**

First, expression evaluation in AngularJS is **caseSensitive** for variables, so... my very first problem was using a single word field in capital way "List" instead of "list".

1. Changed: `$scope.List = [];` to `$scope.list = [];`
2. As Chev noted in his answer, I also missed the two-way binding in `scope`. Added it as two-way (`'='`)

   2.1 Optional - Renamed the directive isolated scope field "list" to "listinherit" (The renaming is not needed, I did it just for more clarification...):
3. Added the attribute to bind with controller scope

   ```
   <hitmap id="mapSearch" lat="25" lng="-80.4" listinherit="list" />
   ```
4. Changed the watch expression to watch the **IsolatedScope** field `"listinherit"`and ...

   Voilá! It worked as expected!

   ```
    $scope.$watch('listinherit', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if ($scope.listinherit != undefined) { alert('Yeah !') } 
    },true);
   ```

Check the solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriobarreto/5kvhkw5j/2/)